# my django project was displaying images but doesnt display images anymore after i deployed it to render

Tags: python, django, server-side-rendering

my Django project was working fine but after me deploying it using the render server the images do not display anymore like the logo what could be the cause and how can I solve it

I tried using AWS S3 buckets but that failed and other than that failed its too complex I guess but is their some sort of easier way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information for investigate your problem. But i think you need check how work your static files:

- check if you run `collectstatic` in production
- check if `STATIC_ROOT` point to directory with static files
- check how static files processing on prod. server (may be `whitenoise` will help)